# Creating a materialized view which inherits the permissions of the user making the view call

Tags: postgresql, permissions, materialized-views

I am trying to create a materialized view within a function, and the view needs to have the permission for the user making the view call from within my application. I know that this can be done in a function, but is there a way to do this on a view when creating the view from within my function?

In short — I'm creating a view in a function; is there a way to grant permissions to the view within the function?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.my_function()
     RETURNS void AS $body$
DECLARE
     view_name TEXT := '';
BEGIN
     view_name := $vn$
     CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW schema.view_name_mv
     ( 
          "column1",
          "column2",
          "column3"
     )
     as 
     select 
          column1, 
          column2,
          column3
     from schema.table_name;
     $vn$;
END; 
$body$
     LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Explicitly issue a `GRANT` statement in the function right after you create the materialized view:

   ```
   GRANT SELECT ON "schema".view_name_mv TO appuser;
   ```
2. Use `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` so that any future tables, views and materialized views in that schema get privileges for the user:

   ```
   ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE creator IN SCHEMA "schema"
      GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO appuser;
   ```

   This assumes that the user who creates the materialized view is `creator`.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing this, I considered that there are instances when you may also need to make a function call which is creating objects within the database as a user which does not have permissions to create objects. As such, if you want to create a materialized view within a function and the user making the function call has limited permissions then you may want to differentiate whether or not a function should inherit the permissions of the user that created the function or the user making the call to the function. This can be done as follows:

**Security Invoker:** *indicates that the function is to be executed with the privileges of the user that calls it. That is the default.*

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.my_function_si()
    RETURNS void AS $body$
    DECLARE
     view_name TEXT := '';
    BEGIN
     view_name := $vn$
    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW schema.view_name_mv
    ( 
          "column1",
          "column2",
          "column3"
    )
    as 
    select 
          column1, 
          column2,
          column3
    from schema.table_name;
    $vn$;
    END; 
    $body$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE SECURITY INVOKER;
```

Materialized View will inherit the permissions of the user making the call.

**Security Definer:** *SECURITY DEFINER specifies that the function is to be executed with the privileges of the user that created it.*

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.my_function_sd()
    RETURNS void AS $body$
    DECLARE
     view_name TEXT := '';
    BEGIN
     view_name := $vn$
    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW schema.view_name_mv
    ( 
          "column1",
          "column2",
          "column3"
    )
    as 
    select 
          column1, 
          column2,
          column3
    from schema.table_name;
    $vn$;
    END; 
    $body$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Materialized View will inherit the permissions of the user that creates the function.